# Laravel vuejs:ajax post route error

Tags: php, http, laravel-5, vuejs2, axios

I've implemented a post ajax request using axios and vue library ,everything works fine when i am running in development mode (id `localhost:8000`).

But when i run from public folder(ie `localhost/vutest/public`) i my post url is not working as expected .

Here is the post route

```
Route::post('/test','HomeController@testPost');
```

**JS**

```
axios.post('/test',this.user)
                    .then(response => {
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                      this.error=response.data.errors;

                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {

                    });
```

This route (ie `/test`) works fine when i am running from `localhost:8000`

But running the app from `localhost/vuetest/public` ajax post url is not working.

When i check the developer console for the header information

```
Request URL:http://localhost/test
Request Method:POST
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
```

Whats the issue?

**UPDATE**

When i replaced the `\test` with `http://localhost/vuetest/public/test`  its works.

Comment: Sorry, it's very confusing, the issue you are facing is related to vue-router or laravel or your backed API?

Comment: Its related with backend api.